# Using multiple <form>s for displaying dirty

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite new to angular and currently are playing around to figure out how to plan my project (and which of my wishes can be accomplished using angular and bootstrap)

I've already found a solution for my most recent problem but I'm asking whether this is a legitimate approach, or whether it's just a dirty hack an I'm abusing the form and should better achieve it another way.

I have a large form that needs to be sent to the server as a large json object (at least in the first version). In the html I've made several panels (using bootstrap) to group input fields.

Now I'd like to show which panels have been edited and came across the idea to put a form inside/around each panel and just use $dirty like this

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-class="{'panel-info': myform.$dirty}">
  <div class=panel-heading>...</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form name="myform" class="form">
      (skipped: form-group and label)
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSomeInput" ng-model="myCtrl.SomeData">
      ... some more inputs   
    </form> 
  ...
```

Thinking of the old html4 forms (everything I want to be posted in one step has to go inside one form) this approach feels... wrong.

On the other side... sending the data to the server is done using angular, so this doesn't require the form - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're nesting the form elements, so I'd say you're pretty much good to go. Like you said, angular is handling the data binding and sending it to your server.